What is this NPN circuit doing?
I'm trying to make a mod to a board from a device I have, and I'm trying to decipher what a particular circuit on it is doing. I'm somewhat of a hobbyist in circuits, but I'm not 100% sure whats going on here. The input is just a line coming from an external wire/connector to the board, but it will either be 5V or 0V as it is digital logic. I have modeled this in the schematic as a SPDT switch to the voltage source for simplicity.
Note: This circuit was originally modeled with inputs on the right and outputs on the left. I have modified it to be the opposite as per a request from the comments.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I have modeled this circuit in falstad, and from what I can tell it seems like it's some kind of buffer for the input (on the right hand side). The output goes into a pin on an ATMega to be read in.
My attempt at understanding this circuit is as follows: It looks like R2 and R3 are just pulldowns to ground on the off chance that something is left floating, and I guess R4 and R5 are pull ups to 5V? Aside from that, it looks like when Q1 is active, it pulls 5V to ground through R4 thus leaving the output connected to 5V through R5, but when Q1 is inactive, Q2 becomes active through R4 thus pulling 5V to ground through R5 which disables the output pin as it is now being pulled to ground.
Is this circuit just some kind of buffer so it's not pulling too much voltage/current from the input, or is it doing anything more complex than that?

@jsotola This is an English speaking site, so the predominant design rule from people OP wants help from is left to right. It’s corrected now so I’ll delete my comment.

yeah, your analysis sounds valid: it's a buffer of sorts. Technically, it's an open collector output: when your switch is in top position, there's a very low-ohmic path from output to ground. You can thus sink much current with this (think: bright LED between +5V and "output", for example, or a small motor).
The buffering is not symmetrical: in the other switch state, you can't source much current in that state (there's still the 10 kΩ of R5).

Your reverse-engineering of the circuit is correct.
When the input is high, the output will be high, and when input is low, the output will be low.
Why it really is in the circuit is unknown, you need to maybe think about the impedances and voltage levels for both input and output.
The output of this circuit to MCU input is a standard open-drain transistor with 10k pull-up to 5V. This is fine for slow status signals that are on or off, and if the 5V comes from the MCU board then there is no damage even if the circuit input side is driven with 5V, while a direct connection of 5V to unpowered MCU input can damage it. It can sink a lot of current through transistor but source very little through resistor.
The input of this circuit is just a transistor base with series limiting resistor and pull-down for keeping it off when input is floating. It will start turning on somewhere between 1V to 1.5V range which is much earlier than the MCU CMOS input, and CMOS must be driven with definite 0/5V signals. The input also easily accepts much higher voltages, for example 30V only makes it draw about 3mA and dissipates 90mW in the series resistor.
So if you simply use the circuit with 5V/0V inputs and have the inputs and outputs use the same 5V as MCU, you really would not see anything out of the ordinary, it's just what the circuit allows beyond that simple use case.
